# Обратная связь с отбивкой клиенту на указанную почту

Tags: php, форма, оптимизация-сайтов

Подскажите, как сделать в обратной связи 2 письма, одно отправлять админу, другое клиенту.
Админу текст, что поступила заявка от клиента, номер телефона и тд.
А Клиенту - Спасибо Вам огромнейшее, мы с Вами свяжемся (да моему начальнику мало всплывающего окна, он хочет по-максимум).

```
<?
if (array_key_exists('messageFF', $_POST)) {
   $to ="murmur@mail.ru"; /админы

   $to_user =.$_POST['contactFF']; /клиент

   $subject = 'ТЕСТОВОЕ ОБРАЩЕНИЕ НА ЗАЯВКУ';
   $subject = "=?utf-8?b?". base64_encode($subject) ."?=";

   $message = "IP: ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\n\nФ.И.О.: ".$_POST['nameFF']."\n\nРегион: ".$_POST['regionFF']."\n\nГород: ".$_POST['cityFF']."\n\nТелефон: +".$_POST['telFF']."\n\nEmail: ".$_POST['contactFF']."\n\nСообщение: ".$_POST['messageFF']."\n\nЯ, ".$_POST['nameFF'].", даю свое согласие на обработку сайтом моих персональных данных. С Соглашением на обработку персональных данных ознакомлен(-а).";;

   $message2 = "Здравствуйте, Здравствуйте! Мы очень рады, что Вы оставили заявку, Вот вот, мы Вам перезвоним";

   $headers = 'Content-type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"';
   $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
   $headers .= "Date: ". date('D, d M Y h:i:s O') ."\r\n";

   mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

   mail($to_user, $subject, $message2, $headers);

   echo $_POST['nameFF'];
}
?>
```

Очень благодарю за любую помощь! поисковик мне не помог....

Comment: Что не работает в вашем коде?

Comment: Если писать: $to_user =.$_POST['contactFF']; форма в принципе не отрабатывает. Возможно тут я неправильный синтаксис применяю? Если пишу конкретную почту вот так: $to_user ="murmur2@mail.ru,"; админу письмо приходит, а на $to_user нет.

Comment: так немного поколдовав у меня идет отправка второго письма, если писать конкретно, все было из-за кавычек, для примера наглядности... `$to ='admin@mail.ru,'; $to_user ='user@mail.ru'; ` Но вот как правильно оформить $to_user =.$_POST['contactFF'];?

Comment: зачем вам точка `$to_user =.$_POST['contactFF'];` - тут? вы отправляете 2 письма разным пользователям, переменные даже не пересекаются. Собсна если на админ отправляет, то по аналогии и с `$to_user` сделайте. или что не понятно?

Comment: И до кучи я бы посоветовал добавить проверку $_POST['contactFF'] на валидность, чтобы это точно был email-адрес.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (array_key_exists('messageFF', $_POST)) {
   $to ="murmur@mail.ru"; /админы

   $to_user = trim($_POST['contactFF']); /клиент

   $subject = 'ТЕСТОВОЕ ОБРАЩЕНИЕ НА ЗАЯВКУ';
   $subject = "=?utf-8?b?". base64_encode($subject) ."?=";

   $message = "IP: ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\n\nФ.И.О.: ".$_POST['nameFF']."\n\nРегион: ".$_POST['regionFF']."\n\nГород: ".$_POST['cityFF']."\n\nТелефон: +".$_POST['telFF']."\n\nEmail: ".$_POST['contactFF']."\n\nСообщение: ".$_POST['messageFF']."\n\nЯ, ".$_POST['nameFF'].", даю свое согласие на обработку сайтом моих персональных данных. С Соглашением на обработку персональных данных ознакомлен(-а).";;

   $message2 = "Здравствуйте, Здравствуйте! Мы очень рады, что Вы оставили заявку, Вот вот, мы Вам перезвоним";

   $headers = 'Content-type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"';
   $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
   $headers .= "Date: ". date('D, d M Y h:i:s O') ."\r\n";

   mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

   mail($to_user, $subject, $message2, $headers);

   echo $_POST['nameFF'];
}
```

Comment: Не знаю, как Вы это делаете)) я тестила с `$to_user =trim($_POST['contactFF']);` так не отрабатывало!)) это что все из-за пробела?! СПАСИБО ВАМ ОГРОМНОЕ, кстати, если писать одного админа, то у меня не работает с двумя кавычками, только так `$to ='murmur@mail.ru'; /админы`

Comment: это из-за того что вы писали $to_user .= вместо просто =

Comment: нет, писала конкретно так `$to_user =trim($_POST['contactFF']);` не отрабатывает! видимо бубен сломался, Ваш вариант отрабатывает и супер) За что еще раз огромнейшие Благодарности!